# WooCommerce remove shop images in default WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

It appears I cannot remove shop images (and other content) using this code in newest Wordpress theme (Twenty Twenty-Three)

I used hooks from here:  https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/

I dont have anything installed (no plugins) and just this Wordpress theme (Twenty Twenty-Three)

If I add this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'wpv_woocommerce_init');

function wpv_woocommerce_init() {

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );

}
```

I can still see this content in shop page:

[image: https://snipboard.io/N0KRzG.jpg]

Where is this coming from:

```
 data-block-name="woocommerce/product-image"
```

And why cant I remove this using Woocommerce hooks?

Comment: that remove your own replacement for internal wordpress functions, but they are still there, so a function for woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item stull exists, when it is called else you would get an error

Comment: Can you explain more?  This worked for me before and it still works in Wordpress theme 2021, not in newer themes. I get these blocks rendered in shop page and in single product page wehn  I remove some hooks from Shop or single product pages.  I can use any tutorial https://jilt.com/blog/remove-woocommerce-product-images/

Comment: i am not sure what yoz try to do, adda_ction maps an internal function  like woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item to the template function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open remove the action, whenever you call woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item  it doesn't use the function from the template it uses the internal function. this will not remove any images

Comment: but if I remove these actions, example  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );    in woocommerce_init, or in after_setup_theme or template_redirect, (I tried everywhere), it does not remove shop details. I want to remove shop details so I can build my own.

Comment: maybe this approach will fit you better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740935/woocommerce-remove-product-image-from-shop-page-and-single-product-page#

Comment: @nbk I am not trying to remove just image. I want to remove all shop content from woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item to woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item. With the code I showed above it works in Defualt Wordpress themes up to 2021, but not after.

Comment: you should search for the add_habdler that correspont bto your remove, there are more that need to be removed, also you shoukld learn how to debug php code, so thata you can do chnges by yourself

Comment: @nbk but  I have added the code shown in my post, isnt this code correct?  I dont have any errors in php error log.

Comment: I guess the answer is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77108739/is-it-possible-to-use-hooks-in-gutenberg-blocks

Comment: i still can't understand what you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

U can try to use this code to remove the default image in woocommerce.

```
// Remove placeholder image.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_placeholder_img_src', '__return_empty_string' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_placeholder_img', '__return_empty_string' );

// Prevent WooCommerce from showing empty image in gallery.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', function( $html, $post_thumbnail_id ) {
    if ( ! $post_thumbnail_id ) {
        return;
    }
    return $html;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I am not trying to remove just image. I want to remove all shop content from woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item to woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item. With the code I showed above it works in Defualt Wordpress themes up to 2021, but not after.